# Caching issue when deployed flask app with SQLite on google App engine

Tags: python, sqlite, google-app-engine, flask, caching

I'm newborn on Google cloud App engine :), I'm deploying my flask web app to Google App Engine, and everything from GAE looks fine,
but when the user accesses the app the faced an issue. looks like a caching issue for me so far.(hope someone help me im going to be crazy)

**Issue description:**
Any action user takes required to retrieve data from the server-side. the user have to refresh the page to reload the changes (this sometimes the user press refresh more than 3 times.)
Also, after the object ex.(table) loaded with the data retrieved from the server, if the user press again refreshes the page. the page loaded as before any action taken.
And so on page reload showing the latest another page load showing the old content.

What I did till the moment:

I update my app.yaml to be as below:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

default_expiration: "2s"

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: 'vizionflow-5b8735ce1d20.json'

handlers:
- url: /static/css
  static_dir: static/css/
  expiration: '10s'

- url: /static/js
  static_dir: static/js/
  expiration: '5m'

error_handlers:
  - file: error_nopage.html
```

Also, I tried to add on the

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(r):
    """
    Add headers to both force latest IE rendering engine or Chrome Frame,
    and also to cache the rendered page for 10 minutes.
    """
    r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    r.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
    return r
```

Thanks for everyone how could help even with Ideas :)

Comment: The actions you describe are they calling the backend, and have you implemented on the frontend a logic to reload when this actions happen? Or are this actions on the backend and you want them to be relected on the Front end?

Comment: thanks for your reply, these actions happened when they are calling the backend, and on the frontend  it just form post to the backend then page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if the response really returns the headers you're setting in Python? IIRC it was not working for me, as AppEngine is somehow overriding them, so I had to set them in `app.yaml` instead, eg:

```
handlers:
  - url: /my/route
    script: auto
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      Cache-Control: no-cache
```